# PHPUnit doesn't install an executable script

Tags: php, unit-testing, osx-snow-leopard, phpunit, pear

So I installed PHPUnit using PEAR, everything worked fine. The installation showed that everything was installed, and in my `/usr/lib/php` the `PHPUnit` folder is filled with the complete library.

However, I can't find the `phpunit.sh` anywhere. Where is it located? If I try to run `phpunit` on CLI, it doesn't find the command, so it can't be anywhere in the "standard"-binary folders like `/usr/local/bin`.

Do I have to download the script myself? Maybe even compile it myself?

PS: I'm running on OS X 10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
$ pear list phpunit/phpunit
...
script /usr/bin/phpunit
...
```

that's your executable script. No `.sh` appended.

PHPUnit is pure PHP, no need to compile anything.

Comment: please consider adding instructions how to compile phpunit, thanks.

Comment: I fully answered the question. You have no right to demand a solution for a different problem here.